# How to tell requirejs to load only the javascript required by the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm using requirejs in a wordpress plugin. I'm trying to use it so that only the javascript needed for the page is loaded.
My idea is to have a main.js file that loads the js for the current page, but i was wondering how to tell main.js what file to load.

```
require( 
    [ "pages/name-of-the-page" ], // How do i tell require that we are on page x?
    function( page ) { 
        page.start();
    }
);
```

I was thinking about what to use, maybe i should set a cookie server-side, read it and then use that data?Use the url parameters to guess the page?What should i do?

Comment: I don't understand why requirejs would need the name of he page you are on. require is concerned with Javascript mpdules, not with HTML pages...

Comment: @missingno that's because if i'm on page 'a' i want only to load the javascript for page 'a', while on page 'b' i only want to load javascript for page 'b'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem more sensible to just load core JS modules in your `main.js` (since it will be loaded on every page) and then for each page `require` only the code you need.

One crude way is to check in wordpress what page is currently loaded and then load your files there:

```
<?php if (is_page('Contact')): ?>
<script>
    require(['scripts/pages/contact.js']);
    // Note use of a plain js file, and not a module
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then in *contact.js*

```
require(['some/contact/module'], function(contact) {
    // do cool stuff
});
```

I covered [a similar situation in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815454/how-does-requirejs-work-with-multiple-pages-and-partial-views/10816983#10816983) that may help as well.