# AMD / RequireJs add decency on specific pages

Tags: requirejs, amd

Is there a way to have a main script that act like a "global" script for all pages of a site while still have specific page script when using requiere.js.

This would be called on all pages

```
<script data-main="resources/js/main" src="resources/js/libs/require.js"></script>
```

and on other page i would like to add other dependencies without having to create a different main.js script.

Is there any way to do so ?

**EDIT: Just found a way that seems to be working pretty well so far:**

```
<script> require.config({ deps : ['register'] }) </script>
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a global main and a page main scripts, something like this (the data-start is not part of the requirejs, is hand-made as described on the link below):

```
<script data-main="globalmain.js" data-start="page/main" src="require.js"/>
```

More details here: [How to use RequireJS build profile + r.js in a multi-page project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674824/how-to-use-requirejs-build-profile-r-js-in-a-mult-page-project/11730147#11730147)

Comment: That's pretty net, thanks for the link. How ever i found that https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage, is probably an approach that stick closer to the requireJS way

Comment: @silkAdmin, is a very good boilerplate for requirejs, for me is a little verbose though. Good luck ;)