# RequireJS config loading individual modules when they're already included in global module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Alright, I've got a multi-page site with page-specific modules. Each page should load two JS files generated by r.js: main.js, which is a collection of all modules available globally, and "page-name-here".js, which is a collection of the modules only needed for the current page.

I tried to pattern it somewhat off of this response to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11730147/843490.

I also wanted to structure it so that I wouldn't have to explicitly include jQuery as a dependency in every module, but that it would just be loaded and executed first.

Build.js file: http://pastebin.com/XP2cCh18
Main.js file: http://pastebin.com/vsAnm99S

The r.js tool seems to be compiling everything correctly with all modules written into main.js and "page-name-here".js. BUT, when I load the page, require js starts bringing in EVERY global module individually even after main.js has loaded. I assume this is due to global.js not being listed explicitly as a dependency, but I'm unsure of have to tweak it to remedy this.

Any clues? Thanks!