# How do I use Backbone.js with Require.js (r.js), but resulting in 2 files after I optimize it?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, requirejs, r.js

I have followed the basic tutorials (results in one file after you run `r.js`)

The problem is, my `main.js` file at the end is 500KB. That's too big. I want to split it into two files.

I want to optimize my `main.js` file into two files:

1. One that holds the front page and user profile pages, since they're most accessed
2. One that holds all the other pages (ordering, account settings, profile settings, etc.)

Most people will hit the front page and user profile pages, and I want those to load quickly first (while having the other pages load in the background in the 2nd main file)

The problem is, I don't know how to do this.  There are [examples like this online](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage-shim), but these examples do not use Backbone.  They don't cover how to deal with router and app.js

I'm confused...because I only have one `app.js`, one `router.js`...how can I split router.js into two files?

I don't know how to split my project up when dealing with Backbone.

Below is the code

**HTML PAGE (the entry point for my Single Page Application)**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-main='/media/js/main' src='/media/js/lib/requirejs/require-jquery.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    Hello
</body>
</html>
```

**Main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths:{
        jquery: 'lib/requirejs/require-jquery',
        jquery_ui:'lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone:'lib/backbone/backbone-min',
        backbone_viewhelper:'lib/backbone/backbone.viewhelper',
        text: 'lib/requirejs/text',
        birthdaypicker: 'lib/birthdaypicker/bday-picker',
        //more paths
    },
    waitSeconds: 30,
    shim:{
        'underscore':{
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone':{
            deps:[ 'underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'backbone_viewhelper':{
            deps:['underscore','backbone']
        }
    }
});


require([
    'app',
    'json2',
    'jquery_ui',
    'backbone_viewhelper',
    'bootstrap_js',
    'bootstrap_select',
    'birthdaypicker',
    'accounting',
    'numbersonly',
    'main_alert',
    'string_tools',
    'plupload',
    //more things here
], function(App){
    App.initialize();
});
```

**App.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'router'
], function($, _, Backbone, Router){    
    var initialize = function(){
        Router.initialize();
    }
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };

});
```

**Router.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'modules/index/view',
    'modules/home/view',
    'modules/listings_search/view',
    'modules/profile/view',
    //more modules
], function($, _, Backbone, indexView, homeView,searchView, profileView){
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        initialize:function(){
            _.bindAll(this);
        },
        routes:{
            '':'index',
            'home': 'home',
            'register': 'register',
            'login': 'login',
            'listings(/start/:start)(/num/:num)': 'search',
            'listings/create': 'listingsCreate',
            'listings/:listing_id/edit': 'listingsEdit',
            'orders/listings/:listing_id/create': 'ordersCreate',
            'orders/buyer(/start/:start)(/num/:num)': 'ordersListBuyer',
            'orders/seller(/start/:start)(/num/:num)': 'ordersListSeller',
            'orders/:order_id': 'orders',
            'orders/:order_id/messages':'messages',
            '*actions': 'defaultAction'
            //more stuff
        },
        index:function(){
            app_router_view.show(indexView);
        },
        search:function(start, num){
            var options = {
                filters:{
                    start: start,
                    num: num
                }
            };
            app_router_view.show(searchView, options);
        },
        static:function(template){
            app_router_view.show(staticView, { static_view: { template: template }});
        },
        profile:function(){
            app_router_view.show(profileView);
        },
        passResetCode:function(code){
            app_router_view.show(passCodeView, {'code':code});
        },
        //more stuff
        home:function(){
            app_router_view.show(homeView);
        },
        defaultAction:function(actions){
            this.navigate('/', { trigger:true});
        }
    });
    var initialize = function(){
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
        Backbone.history.start({pushState:true, root: '/'});
        $(document).on('click', 'a:not([data-bypass])', function (evt) {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            if(href){
                var protocol = this.protocol + '//';
                if (href.slice(protocol.length) !== protocol && href != '#') {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    app_router.navigate(href, { trigger: true});
                }
            }else{
            }
        });
    };
    return {
        initialize:initialize
    }
});
```

As you can see , my entire app starts with `main.js`, goes to `app.js`, and finally goes to `router.js`.

How can I split this?

Comment: Have you consider removing the size of your all.js by moving some vendor lib to CDN and not packing them inside your all.js file? (e.g. jquery)

Comment: What is the size of this file after being gzipped?  And if you have the option to use nodejs, you could also try something like http://ezeljs.com/ to send a rendered page on the first response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code you have shared, I've created a sample web-app and committed the code in [git-hub](https://github.com/manishcm/modular-backbone).

Application is divided into 2 modules:

- `main` : `contains modules/index/view` and `modules/profile/view`
- `other` : `contains 'modules/order/view` and `modules/search/view`

When you request for `modules/index/view` or `modules/profile/view`, `main.js` is downloaded if not downloaded yet. Similarly when request is placed for `modules/order/view` or `modules/search/view`, `other.js` is downloaded if not downloaded yet. Remember to use `require.js v2.1.10` or greater, as it has bundle feature which is required for generating `other.js`.

You can further modularize it by defining `order, search, profile` as independent modules in `build.js`, so that they are downloaded only when needed.

Output of executing build command :

```
media/js/main.js
----------------
media/js/lib/jquery/jquery-min.js
media/js/lib/underscore/underscore-min.js
media/js/lib/backbone/backbone-min.js
media/js/router.js
media/js/app.js
media/js/main.js
media/js/modules/index/model.js
media/js/modules/index/view.js
media/js/modules/profile/model.js
media/js/modules/profile/view.js

media/js/other.js
----------------
media/js/modules/order/model.js
media/js/modules/order/view.js
media/js/modules/search/model.js
media/js/modules/search/view.js
```

The execution flow goes like this:
`index.html => media/js/main` [it has `index/view, profile/view, app.js` and all the dependencies]. By default Index view is shown, as it is configured for home route.

When Profile links is clicked, no more files are downloaded, as `main.js` is already downloaded.
When Search / Order links are clicked, `other.js` is downloaded.

Comment: Hi @Manish, do you know why I get this error when optimizing? ```Tracing dependencies for: "other".  Error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/mypath/media/js/other.js'```

Comment: @TIMEX Can you share `main.js` file?

Answer (score 3):

I've created [an example](https://github.com/lddubeau/backbone-split) to show how it could be done. It contains a skeleton of Backbone application. The application there is split into:

- a `main` bundle which contains the core of the application and only
  renders a "main" view (called `views/app` here),
- and a `secondary` bundle which contains all other views.

The `secondary` bundle is loaded only as needed. In this application this means that it should be loaded only when the `foo` or `bar` views are used, and not before. (You can verify this by inspecting network operations in your browser.)

The key points are:

1. The view in `views/app` is the "main" view of the
   application. Loading it instantiates and renders the view right
   away.
2. The `js/router` module does not use the other views directly. It
   calls `require` to load the view first. **This makes the `foo` and
   `bar` function asynchronous.**
3. This is the part of the `build.js` file that divides the
   application into two bundles:

   ```
   modules: [
       {
           name: "main"
       },
       {
           name: "secondary",
           // There no module named secondary in the source, so create it.
           create: true,
           // Make sure to include all the views other than the main one.
           include: [
               "views/foo",
               "views/bar"
           ],
           // Exclude everything we've included in `main`.
           exclude: ["main"]
       }
   ]
   ```
4. The optimized version needs an initial configuration like this:

   ```
     bundles: {
        "secondary": ["views/foo", "views/bar"]
     }
   ```

   This tells RequireJS that the modules `views/foo` and `views/bar`
   are loaded by loading `secondary`.

Please read the `README.md` file for more details.

Comment: ty @Louis I just find what i need:)

Answer (score 0):

In your build profile you can specify how many modules do you want to create and which dependencies they have to include (see http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#basics).

You can see the options here https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js , the part you're interested in starts on line 350.

Also see [How to use RequireJS build profile + r.js in a multi-page project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674824/how-to-use-requirejs-build-profile-r-js-in-a-multi-page-project/11730147#11730147) for a deeper answer

Answer (score -3):

Splitting the code into two files is not the way to go.

Splitting the code into two files will only increase load times overall, as extra wrapper code would be needed. Also, splitting the code **may** unnecessarily increase the modularity of the code, causing design problems in future.

The way to go would to be to lazy-load the routed files (so you load your front page and user profile pages first), and then you can load the other files in the background after you've done loading the front page and user profile pages.

It is possible to split it - don't get me wrong - but doing so would just create unnecessary code, and really wouldn't help.

[Here a link that may help.](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/lazy-loading-javascript-with-requirejs/)

Comment: What TIMEX is trying to do is to reduce the time from which the user requests the page to the time the page is ready to operate. In *this* context, it *makes absolute sense* to cut the application so that only the bare essentials are loaded *initially* and the rest that users may or may not get to later is loaded later, in the background. I'm speaking from experience actually using RequireJS in production.