# How to work with require function React.js charts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

I wanted to run this demo https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs

**Installation** (I have run this part)

> This is a CommonJS component only (to be used with something like Webpack or Browserify)
>
> ```
> npm install --save react-chartjs
> ```
>
> You must also include chart.js and React as dependencies.
>
> ```
> npm install --save chart.js@^1.1.1 react react-dom
> ```

I don't know how to run this below part:

**Example Usage**

```
var LineChart = require("react-chartjs").Line;

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <LineChart data={chartData} options={chartOptions} width="600" height="250"/>
  }
});
```

This is my complete html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script src="build/react.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/react-chartjs.js"></script>

<body>
<script>
var LineChart = require("react-chartjs").Line;

/*var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <LineChart data={chartData} options={chartOptions} width="600" height="250"/>
  }
});
*/
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

It generates errors like:

> test.html:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined(…)

or

> test.html:18 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

### Update

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script src="build/react.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/react-chartjs.js"></script>
<script src="js/require.js"></script>

<body>
<script type='text/babel'>
var LineChart = require("react-chartjs").Line;

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <LineChart data={chartData} options={chartOptions} width="600" height="250"/>
  }
});

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

now the error is:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "react-chartjs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])(…)
```

Comment: I highly recommend using Facebook's official react starter app. You'll have a way better time https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Comment: but i wanted to use this only for charts

Comment: i think i just need directions :(

Comment: for babel to work properly the way you are doing it, make sure you add `<script type='text/babel' src='link/to/babel'>. As far as inline html requiring I belive you need to add a require.js script tag in there as well. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697238/load-requirejs-module-inline-the-html-body

Comment: Then why not use chartjs directly instead of the React wrapper?

Comment: @azium will it be right way to do that? i just wanted to know right way i am new in it. i can add it directly

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: I mean.. don't use React at all... if you're going to use React then follow the instructions in the `create-react-app` repo and start using that project instead of what you have.

Comment: It's *literally* designed to be the absolute easiest way to start a React project, and instructions are dead simple. I believe in you man.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Use [ReactDOM](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html) to inject the React (app) component into your html.

Essentially, make a div with an id, then call ReactDOM, like so:

**HTML**

```
<!-- React app component will be injected in the div below -->
<div id="app-area"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('app-area'));
```