# How do I instantiate require.js modules on different pages, partials with codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, requirejs, organization

I'm trying to update the javascript on a large scale, php/codeigniter based website. It has many, many php partials for code being loaded onto certain pages, but only one footer, header. Most of the partials have inline script tags in them for loading javascript. This needs to be fixed and because the site is very modular with components being used multiple times across pages, require.js seems like a pretty good solution.

So, it's instantiate javascript, we typically do this.

```
<script type="javascript" src="../js/scriptname.js">
<script type="javascript">
     DP.scriptname.init(parameters)
</script>
```

I'd like to get away from this and just have a have a single entry point for the js using require.

My question is this: what's the best way to instantiate javascript for certain pages using require? Do I need I need to continue including my scripts in the partial and then do something like writing a require module for that specific page and then wrap it all in my data-main script like [this](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage)? We're planning on using Backbone and Marionette as well, but I won't be able to use the Backbone router to do anything like setting hash URLs. Should I use the URLs to instantiate my require modules perhaps?

Ok, hope someone can help. My experience has typically been in building single page websites. This is different. Thanks

Cam

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I understand your question correctly, you can use Require JS in such way.

First of all, write a config in which you can describe mapping between module names and concrete files. For example:

```
requirejs.config({        
    baseUrl: 'js/modules' // by default load any module using this path
});
```

After that you should refactor your existing module and adjust it to the AMD format (see http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)

As a result of this step you will have something like this (let's say in file 'js/modules/scriptname.js'):

```
// module has the same name as the file, which contains it - "scriptname"
define(function () {
    // define the module value by returning a value
    return function () {};
});
```

And as a final step you can refactor your inline script and use this module in such way:

```
<script type="javascript">
    // when we place name of the module as a first argument of the "define" 
    // function, Require JS find file that contains it and load it asynchronously
    define(["scriptname"], function (scriptname) {
        // "scriptname" now contains value that we recieve from the module definition
        scriptname.init(parameters);
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Note. My solution based on this section of official Require JS documentation: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles

Comment: Thanks v2p, but I don't see how this helps. How do I fire the init of scripts in questions only on urls that I want it to fire on, while only having the one script tag for the whole project? Should I use the backbone marionette router to watch my urls and then fire the appropriate code as necessary? The more I think about it, the more this seems a backbone as opposed to a require.js question.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to come up a lot, so I'll point you to some resources that may help:

- How does RequireJS work with multiple pages and partial views? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10816983/617615
- Modular HTML components with RequireJS - http://simonsmith.io/modular-html-components-with-requirejs/
- Example RequireJS-based project that has multiple pages that share a common set of modules -  https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage

Comment: Using these solutions though, wouldn't I have to have multiple script tags in my code base (as opposed to just keeping it in my one footer partial) and wouldn't I have to use that script tags inside the partial, which would put in somewhere in the middle of my pages mark up. I don't really like the idea of doing this. Is there not another way to organize things? Thanks Simon.