# requirejs define is not defined

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, requirejs

I'm trying to implement knockoutjs and requirejs to my asp.net mvc app.

So, here's what I have.

**Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml**

```
<html>
<body>
  @RenderBody()
  <script src="~/Scripts/require.js" data-main="/Scripts/app/main"></script>
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
<html>
```

**Scripts/main.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/Scripts',
    paths: {
        ko: '/Scripts/knockout-3.3.0'
    }
});
```

**Views/Product/Index.cshtml** (one of my views)

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: products">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.product"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script src="~/Scripts/app/product.js"></script>
@section scripts {
  // Some scripts here
}
```

**Scripts/app/product.js**

```
define(['ko'], function (ko) {
    var data = [
        { name: 'Product1' },
        { name: 'Product2' }
    ];

    var Product = function () {
        this.name = ko.observable()
    };

    var productVm = {
        products: ko.observableArray([]),
        load: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                productVm.products.push(new Product()
                        .name(data[i].name));
            }
        }
    }

    productVm.load();
    ko.applyBindings(productVm);
});
```

Just in case you need to see my folder structure

```
Solution
- Scripts
-- app
--- product.js
-- require.js
-- knockout-3.3.0.js
- Views
-- Product
--- Index.cshtml
-- Shared
--- _Layout.cshtml
```

Then, once I navigate to my products index page. I got a `define is not define` error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include following in your `main.js`

```
require(["app/product"], function () {

});
```

And modify `index.html` as follows

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: products">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.name"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
@section scripts {

}
```

If you intend to use RequireJS for multi page application, then also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815454/how-does-requirejs-work-with-multiple-pages-and-partial-views).

Comment: Wow. It's now actually working. So your saying if I have many `define()` modules. I need to include it in the `main.js` one by one? But how would the `product.js` know what html file will it apply its bindings to?

Comment: @BoyPasmo for using require.js for multi page application, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815454/how-does-requirejs-work-with-multiple-pages-and-partial-views) answer. You have to make some adjustments to your `_layout.cshtml` file.