# Ajax request not fired form partial page when the main page also has an ajax request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, requirejs

In my _layout.cshtml I have a partial view that includes js trough requirejs.

```
<script data-main="/Scripts/Search" src="/Scripts/require.js"></script>
```

In this js file I use the following to populate a knockout vm.

```
    $.getJSON("/Search/Index", function (data) {
        self.availableCities(data.AvailableCities);
    });
```

This works well on all pages except when my main view also has an ajax request.

```
    <script data-main="/Scripts/Index" src="/Scripts/require.js"></script>


    $.getJSON("/Property/All", function (data) {
        self.properties(data);
    });
```

Here is my require config, it is the same for the partial and the main view.

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/Scripts",
    paths: {
        "text": "text",
        "knockout": "knockout-3.3.0",
        "jquery": "jquery-2.1.3.min"
    },
    shim: {
        "jquery": { exports: "$" }
    }
});
```

When the main page has an ajax request only this request is fired, I am not sure how to fix this. It looks like a configuration issue, tested it in both Firefox an Chrome so it does not appear to be browser specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out having multiple `<script data-main="/Scripts/Search" src="/Scripts/require.js"></script>` tags in one page isn't such a bright idea.

I figured it out after some more research, 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10816983/1868690) question has a good solution if you run into a similar problem.

Basically you need one 'main.js' file and add the other page components via the require logic.

---

**Edit:**

Doing this may result in the following knockout error:

> Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

To fix this I have used the following binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
    init: function () {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

To enable this binding handler on containerless elements use the following:

```
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.stopBinding = true;
```

Apply the following binding around the partial view. To prevent the main-page from binding to the elements in the partial.

```
<!-- ko stopBinding: true-->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Finally use ko.applyBinings on the partialview like this:

```
ko.applyBindings(new partialViewModel(), document.getElementById("your-partial"));
```